# Android - How to set a Button text with utf8 encoding

Tags: android

Here I have a problem when setting a Button text with some String encoded in utf8. ¿How can I change the button encoding so no strange characters appear?

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("murciélago");
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I guess it's more a source code file encoding issue. Make sure that your file is stored as UTF-8. If you're using Eclipse you can set that globally for all projects or locally for your app project (right click -> properties). However, you will have to open the offending source file first and save it again with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you should use localisation.
In res folder create new folder values-es

and inside define strings.xml wrote a line like `<string name="murcielago">Murciélago</string>` 
than call

```
button.setText(R.id.murcielago);
```

with this solution, if user have Spanish language for deafult settings it will work. for testing you can create this line `<string name="murcielago">Murciélago</string>` in strings.xml inside values folder

Comment: The problem is that string is created dynamically (the code above was just a much reduced example) and all users, whether having default settins spanish or not, must see the proper string.